# jquery dropdown onchange not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, dropdown

Working on a multi dropdown, where the first dropdown shows a second dropdown depending on the selection and second dropdown selection returns a relevant message. So far working fine in Chrome / FF but no luck in Safari/iOS.

```
$(function(){
$('#groups').on('change', function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    var sub = $('#sub_groups');
    $('option', sub).filter(function(){
        if (
             $(this).attr('data-group') === val 
          || $(this).attr('data-group') === 'SHOW'
        ) {
          if ($(this).parent('span').length) {
            $(this).unwrap();
          }
        } else {
          if (!$(this).parent('span').length) {
            $(this).wrap( "<span>" ).parent().hide();
          }
        }
    });
});
$('#groups').trigger('change');
});

$(function() {
  $('#sub_groups').change(function(){
    $('.messages').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<style>
.messages {color: #000; display: none;}
</style>

<select id="groups">
    <option value='0'>Select 1</option>
    <option value='zone1'>main group 1</option>
    <option value='zone2'>main group 2</option>
    <option value='zone3'>main group 3</option>
</select>
<select id="sub_groups">
    <option data-group='SHOW' value='0'>Select 2</option>
    <option data-group='zone1' value='message1'>option 1 </option>
    <option data-group='zone1' value='message1'>option 2 </option>
    <option data-group='zone2' value='message2'>option 3 </option>
    <option data-group='zone2' value='message2'>option 4 </option>    
    <option data-group='zone3' value='message3'>option 5 </option>    
    <option data-group='zone3' value='message4'>option 6 </option>    
</select>

<div class="output">
   <div id="message1" class="messages">message 1</div>
   <div id="message2" class="messages">message 2</div>
   <div id="message3" class="messages">message 3</div>
   <div id="message4" class="messages">message 4</div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: hey, i tried your code out. I works well in safari for me. I think some other part of your code might be interfering with the working of your function. did you get any error in the console?

Comment: Which version of Safari? It works for me. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ggcyufgj/

Comment: Safari version 9.1.1 and unfortunately still not showing correct messages